# how do i get rid of the error in my python 3.0 program?

Tags: python

I don't understand what is wrong with my syntax. its a program to get a long number.
code:

```
int_num=input('enter digits')
long_num=''
While int_num.isdigit()== True:
    long_num= long_num+int_num
    int_num=input('enter digits')    
print('long',long_num)
```

error:

```
File "<ipython-input-1-c68f222d7f2f>", line 4
    While int_num.isdigit()== True:
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

thanks.

Comment: While-> while. Case sensitive.

Comment: thank bro. i'll never make that mistake again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write "W" of while in upper case,as **while** is case sensitive, replace this with your line

```
while int_num.isdigit()== True:
```

and all works fine